# How to allow only admins to register new users in identityserver4

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, authorization, identityserver4

I am developing an application using ASP .Net core and i am using identityserver4 as my Identity Provider with an angular front-end. currently anybody can access the registration page on my IDP and register as a new user. i want to limit this action to only admins. How can i achieve this? should the IDP be registed also as a client in order to be able to be authenticated after a user login or is it a bad practice? I am open for any suggestions, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the usual authorization patterns inside IdentityServer and protect the registration page using the authorize attribute like:

```
[Authorize("Admin")]
```

Then just register a policy in your startup class like and check for the desired claim, like admin or as I show in this example below that your name must be alice:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            {
                var user = context.User;

                return user.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "name" &&
                                              claim.Value == "alice");
            }
        ));
});
```

So you don't need to register IdentityServer as its own client.

Comment: It is not working, when i inspect the `var user` object it has no claims.

Comment: EDIT: i am sending the Bearer token with the request but IdentityServer4 is redirecting me to login

Comment: You don't need to send any tokens to IdentityServer to access the admin pages, when you login to IdentityServer you get a separate session-cookie with it, so you don't need to do anything than checking the logged in user for the desired claims.

Comment: it looks like no session-cookie is being sent with the request from my angular client. do you have any idea why or how should i debug it?

Comment: i have tried this solution and it worked great for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765570/accessing-protected-api-on-identityserver4-with-bearer-token